# Javascript: Email Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I am having trouble with my email validation code using function validateEmail (str). Any suggestions?

```
//validates email address form
function validateEmail (str)
    {
    var retVal;
    var atpos=retVal.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=retVal.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpost+2 || dotpos+2>=retVal.length)
    {
    retVal = false;         
    return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: I'm using a basic form of `<form name="PizzaForm">
<font face="Courier New">
Email: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="email" type="text" size="50"/><br/></font></p><input type="button" onClick="doSubmit()" value="Submit Order"/></form>`

Comment: and calling it with `function doSubmit() var theEmail = document.PizzaForm.email.value;
if (validateEmail(theEmail)) {alert("The email format is ok!") ;       }else { alert("Invalid email format!"    +"\n\nThe Email address must be in one of the following formats:"
+"\n\ta@a\t – valid"
+"\n\t.@.\t – valid"
+"\n\ta@@@@@@@@a\t – valid"
+"\n\t\/*..@;;;fred\t – valid"                    +"\n\t@cccc@\t  – invalid, the @ character is in the first and last positions");}`

Comment: The actual error in your code is `atpost` is typo'd. See my answer for how you *should* do this, though.

Comment: *What* trouble do you have? Also, please post the complete function not only its beginning.

Comment: You realize it's perfectly valid for the right side of the @ sign to have an IP address, right?

Comment: I fixed my typo `atpost` but it is still not working

Comment: you don't have the same number of `}`s as `{`s in what you've pasted, nor do you default `retVal` to `true` anywhere/`return` in case did not enter the `if`

Comment: @user3625451 You do realize you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23592604/edit) your question instead of adding important stuff in the comments? Please go to the help center to learn how this site work. We are **NOT** a forum!

Answer (score 4):

Any suggestions? Yes. Don't.

```
<input type="email" />
```

Problem solved!

---

It should be noted that use of HTML5 features will make for a beautiful web... provided the browser supports it. The reason being, a failed validation will cause the browser to notify the user of the error in a non-intrusive and consistent, native manner.

Older browsers will not be able to validate in this way, however due to the specification stating that unrecognised `type` values should default to `text`, HTML5 is fully backwards compatible, way back into IE5.5 and almost certainly even earlier - maybe even IE1!

This lack of validation is *not an issue*. Validation should *always* be handled server-side, regardless of what validation you have on the client-side. As an example, in PHP, you would pass it through [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter-var) with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` filter.

Comment: This will not work in older browsers (mostly Internet Explorer < 10) or safari.

Comment: @Sebb So? People who insist on disabling Windows Update should be punished with a less beautiful web, in my opinion.

Comment: You reminded me about [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-PEAMgnO_c7c/UDiplYKPk3I/AAAAAAAAADg/FJXNlXnN2X8/s1600/PROBLEM_SOLVED.jpg) )))

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yep, but if you're a commercial programmer there's no way you lock out many customers just because you think their IT admin should enable win update.

Comment: So maybe the OP is writing something for a corporate who is running IE8 or IE9.

Comment: @Sebb Please explain how "not having instant validation of your email address" constitutes "locking out many customers". So you have to submit the form and have the server complain at you for typing it wrong. Ooh, how "90's". Fits with your browser, doesn't it?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The problem isn't the browser site validation but using a html5 element which isn't supported in the browser which most companies still use. I'm not happy about it either but you can't lock out commercial customers just because you think diffrently than their admin/boss.

Comment: @Sebb Erm... "not supported". Right. So I guess the "if `type` is not recognised, the user agent will fall back to `type=text`" part of the specification of HTML3.2, which is the whole reason HTML5 is backwards compatible, is completely lost then?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yep, but with this fallback we're back in the "90's" as mentioned above. Using Javascript will grant a good experience to all users, including those who are still forced to use IE.

Comment: @Sebb I have edited my answer to elaborate further on browser compatibility. You would mind taking a look and letting me know what you think of said edit?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I also didn't mean to remove server side validation;  client side is just a better user experience. But thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem of your code is that you create an empty variable (`var retVal`) and then you check this variable instead of the given string:

```
var retVal;
var atpos=retVal.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=retVal.lastIndexOf(".");
```

The correct code is

```
function validateEmail (str)
{
  var retVal;
  var atpos=str.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos=str.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpost+2 || dotpos+2>=str.length)
  {
    retVal = false;         
    return retVal;
  }
  // further code
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, what is the difference between the "correct code" and my original code? also I called retVal in a previous segment `function validateText()
    {
    var retVal = true;
    if (0 == document.PizzaForm.email.value.length){validationMessages += "\nEmail field is missing.";         retVal = false;}     
return retVal;}`

Comment: The function has one parameter - `str` - which probably contains the string to check. In your original code, you create a new ***empy*** var called `retVal` and you check ***this*** variable for being an email, which is obviously failing.